# If $f$ and $f'^2$ are integrables, then $f$ tends to $0$ in $\pm\infty$

Tags: integration, limits

$f$ is a real function such that $f'$ is also continuous.

Thank you.

Comment: integrable = Lebesgue-integrable?

Comment: isnt $f(x)=x$ integrable?

Comment: That's not true. If $f$ is mostly equal to $0$, but it has "bumps" at regular intervals, where the bumps get narrower and narrower, but they all have the same height, then it's possible to do that in a manner that makes $f$ and $f^2$ integrable, but $f$ does not converge as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Arthur You can prove that the limit class contains 0, so if the limit exists, it must be 0.

Comment: In your most recent edit, you state $f'$ continuous, but the title says $f^2$ continuous. Which is it? Both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Counterexample to $\boldsymbol{f}$ and $\boldsymbol{f^2}$ integrable $\boldsymbol{\implies\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0}$**

Consider
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }x\in\left[n,n+\frac1{n^2}\right)\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
0&\text{if }x\in\left[n+\frac1{n^2},n+1\right)\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

**Answer to adjusted question**

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\to\infty}\sup_{h\in[0,1]}\left|\,f(a+h)-f(a)\,\right|
&\le\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_a^{a+1}\left|\,f'(x)\,\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_a^{a+1}f'^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}\\
&\le\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_a^\infty f'^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}\\[6pt]
&=0\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_a^{a+1}\left|\,f(x)\,\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_a^\infty\left|\,f(x)\,\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
For find $A$ so that for $a\ge A$
$$
\sup_{h\in[0,1]}\left|\,f(a+h)-f(a)\,\right|\le\frac\epsilon2\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\int_a^{a+1}\left|\,f(x)\,\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\le\frac\epsilon2\tag{4}
$$
Because of $(4)$, for some $x\in [a,a+1]$, $\left|\,f(x)\,\right|\le\frac\epsilon2$. Then, because of $(3)$, we have that for all $x\in[a,a+1]$,
$$
\left|\,f(x)\,\right|\le\epsilon\tag{5}
$$
and since $a\ge A$ was otherwise arbitrary, we get $(5)$ for all $x\ge A$.

Comment: If you were worried about the $L^\infty$ norm, I have replaced it with $\sup$. Otherwise, everything uses only basic formulas that work for both Riemann and Lebesgue integrals.